# JSON string array without Keys into a GoLang struct

Tags: json, go

I am trying to parse JSON that is submitted from a `POST` request into a struct in a web service to send email. The following JSON is submitted in the body of the request.

```
{
  "body": {
    "template": "abctemplate.html",
    "params": {
      "name": "Chase",
      "email": "1234@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  "to": [
    "abc@gmail.com",
    "xyz@gmail.com"
  ],
  "cc": [
    "xxx@example.com",
    "yyy@example.com"
  ],
  "replyTo": {
    "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
    "name": "Jack"
  },
  "bcc": "ccc@gmail.com",
  "subject": "Hello, world!"
}
```

This is mapped and read into the following struct

```
type emailData struct {
    Body struct {
        Template string            `json:"template"`
        Params   map[string]string `json:"params"`
    } `json:"body"`
    To      map[string]string `json:"To"` // TODO This is wrong
    CC      string            `json:"cc"` // TODO this is wrong
    ReplyTo struct {
        Email string `json:"email"`
        Name  string `json:"name"`
    }
    BCC     string `json:"bcc"`
    Subject string `json:"subject"`
}
```

Both the 'to' and 'cc' JSON fields are string arrays of unknown length and do not have keys. Is there a way to map the string arrays into the struct fields? I've tried the two different ways where there are `// TODO` tags with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `cc` and `to` are json arrays which you can unmarshal into Go slices without worrying about the length.

```
type emailData struct {
    Body struct {
        Template string            `json:"template"`
        Params   map[string]string `json:"params"`
    } `json:"body"`
    To      []string `json:"to"`
    CC      []string `json:"cc"`
    ReplyTo struct {
        Email string `json:"email"`
        Name  string `json:"name"`
    }
    BCC     string `json:"bcc"`
    Subject string `json:"subject"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Pi_5aSs922

Answer (score 1):

Use the below to convert the json to struct in golang:

[Json-goStruct](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/)

Take care of the maps, which might be go struct and vice-versa.